# Setting a local bool to control flow

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an issue in Python where I want to do a while loop and ask the player to input number of dice and the number of sides to do random dice rolls. On the second loop and any additional loops I want to ask if they would like to continue. If they input 'n' or 'no' then the program exits.

I was able to get this logic working with a global variable and changing that variable in my function after the first time it is called so the second time the user would be asked if they want to continue, however from my understanding using global variables like this is not a very Python-way of doing things. I would like to improve this.

The following code works except for the fact that the user will never be prompted to exit. I know this is because they variable keeps getting set back to True at the beginning of the while loop, but I don't know how to set a flag without resorting to a global variable.

How do I set a True/False variable locally (not-globally) and use it to control flow in the program?

```
import sys
import random

def get_user_input(first_loop):
    if not first_loop:
        another_time = input("Would you like to roll another time?")
        if another_time.lower() in ['n', 'no']:
            sys.exit()
    # This allows the code above to output on additional loops.
    first_loop = False
    return first_loop

while True:
    # How do I not reset this back to True each time the program loops?
    first_loop = True

    get_user_input(first_loop)

    number_of_dice = int(input("Enter the number of dice you would like to roll: "))
    number_of_sides = int(input("Enter the number of sides for the dice: "))

    # create the dice_total list so each time we create a roll in the loop, 
    # it can be added to a list and the total calculated
    dice_total = []

    for die in range(number_of_dice):
        random_roll = random.randrange(1, number_of_sides)
        print("You rolled: ", random_roll)
        dice_total.append(random_roll)

    dice_total = sum(dice_total)
    print("The total of the dice rolled is: ", dice_total)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close.

```
# move this outside the loop
first_loop = True

while True:
    if not first_loop:
        get_user_input()
    first_loop = False
```

And no need to use `first_loop` in the `get_user_input` function itself:

```
def get_user_input():
    another_time = input("Would you like to roll another time?")
    if another_time.lower() in ['n', 'no']:
        sys.exit()
```

---

It would be better to return `True`/`False` and act accordingly instead of using `sys.exit` in a function (gives you more control):

```
def get_user_input():
    another_time = input("Would you like to roll another time?")
    return not another_time.lower() in ['n', 'no']
```

And then you can do:

```
while True:
    if not first_loop:
        if not get_user_input():
            # break out of the loop
            break
```

Comment: Doesn't this make it a global variable or do I not understand global vars correctly?

Comment: This code doesn't use global variable. It does move the `first_loop` variable outside the loop to be initialized once. Generally speaking the `global` keyword is a code smell that makes the code less modular and less maintainable.

Comment: @ReutSharabani A global variable is one that isn't local to a function / method, i.e. that exists at file scope. Pulling the initialization a variable out of a loop does not make it global. It is still local to the surrounding function.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the variable in a `list`. This will allow you to change its value in the `get_user_input()` function and avoid making it a global variable.

```
import sys
import random

def get_user_input(first_loop):
    if not first_loop[0]:  # access value in the list
        another_time = input("Would you like to roll another time?")
        if another_time.lower() in ['n', 'no']:
            sys.exit()
    # This allows the code above to output on additional loops.
    first_loop[0] = False
    return first_loop[0]  # access value in the list

while True:
    # How do I not reset this back to True each time the program loops?
    first_loop = [True]  # change to a list

    get_user_input(first_loop)

    number_of_dice = int(input("Enter the number of dice you would like to roll: "))
    number_of_sides = int(input("Enter the number of sides for the dice: "))

    # create the dice_total list so each time we create a roll in the loop,
    # it can be added to a list and the total calculated
    dice_total = []

    for die in range(number_of_dice):
        random_roll = random.randrange(1, number_of_sides)
        print("You rolled: ", random_roll)
        dice_total.append(random_roll)

    dice_total = sum(dice_total)
    print("The total of the dice rolled is: ", dice_total)
```

Comment: I was hoping to do this without global variables, but thanks.

Comment: It can be done without global variables. See updated answer.